# MySQL: Upgraded from 5.1 to 5.6 - no problem?

Tags: mysql

We're using Yum to maintain MySQL and our MySQL server only hosts a largish Drupal database.

We recently upgraded via Yum from 5.1 to 5.6. The process went like so:

1. Ran a mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction
2. Un-installed MySQL 5.1 via yum
3. Removed our mysql data folder (/var/lib/mysql)
4. Installed the mysql 5.6 repo package for Yum and ran $ yum update, which updated the mysql client and libraries to 5.6.
5. Installed MySQL 5.6 server via Yum.
6. Imported our 5.1 dump file
7. Ran mysql_upgrade without any errors or warnings reported.
8. Checked databases, users and application worked ok, and it seems to be the case.

I've read up on the [MySQL documentation on updating versions with Yum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/updating-yum-repo.html) and it says not to use Yum and to [upgrade to 5.5 first](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading.html) - the tricky part there is that there isn't an official 5.5 repo around anymore.

Different [upgrade guides say different things](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/89674/how-can-i-upgrade-my-mysql-5-1-to-mysql-5-6-and-migrate-data), but the path taken above was an amalgamation of different guides based on circumstances. So my question is, can anyone see any issues with the upgrade path listed?

Comment: [This page](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-upgrade-problems) does a good job of explaining some of differences between the different versions of MySQL. I'm not sure that they'll affect us using only Drupal though - which should already be compatiable with MySQL 5.6.